# loading and using data with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to understand the logic of it, so I just post some generic code:

1) I get the data from a JSON file with the service "loadData":

```
return {
        myData: function(){
           return $http.get(path + "data.json");
        }
}
```

2) In the main controller:

```
loadData.myData().then(function(result){
      $scope.vm.myData = result.data;
});
```

then, wherever I look for that with:

```
console.log($scope.vm)
```

I have the all object with the data inside, instead, if I look for:

```
console.log($scope.vm.myData)
```

I have always "undefined", and also I cannot use it in any function (the only way is to look for it inside the function above).
What I'd like to have is just to get some data at the begin and then use it wherever I need it.

Comment: This should work from just what you wrote. Can you post a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Try the `console.log` inside your success function from the promise.

Comment: when you log out `$scope.vm` your browser won't actually look inside the vm object until you expand it in your console. At the time you run `console.log` the `myData` field is undefined but by the time you expand it in the console the http call has returned and the `myData` field has been set.

Comment: @MarkC.: inside the success I can read it, but I cannot use it from there.

Comment: The console statement is executing before the promise returns.

Comment: @rob: ok, thanks, now I understand the "why", but how can I solve the problem? Using $timeout doesn't help.

Comment: Anything that depends on `$scope.vm.myData` should be executed/called from inside the successful resolution of the Promise.

Comment: @MarkC.: thank you. In fact I created my application based on it...but actually it's no what I wanted. For my "logic" it's quite simple: I get the data, I store it in a variable and then I use it. Instead, using it inside the promise everytime it means load the data everytime, and there's something wrong with that...I suppose.

Comment: I think you may need to reformat your question with your intentions and current architecture and desired architecture for us to actually help you.

Comment: @MarkC.: my point is the conclusion of my question: "What I'd like to have is just to get some data at the begin and then use it wherever I need it.". I'll try to edit the question and explaining me better. Thanks

Comment: You can use it whenever you need it, after you load it. You have to architect your application accordingly, but once the promise is fulfilled you will be able to access your data

Comment: @MarkC.: maybe I'm missing something: when I talk about using the promise I mean use: loadData.myData().then(function(result){$scope.vm.myData = result.data; //DO WHEREVER YOU WANT WITH THAT HERE}); But doing that means reload (from cache, after the first time, of course) the data.json everytime (I checked it with the console)...is it right???

Answer (score 0):

If your code looks something like this, then the second console statement is firing before the asynchronous call comes back (i.e. before the promise resolves).

```
loadData.myData()
   .then(function(result) {
      $scope.vm.myData = result.data;
      console.log(1, $scope.vm);  // Runs when the promise resolves
   });
console.log(2, $scope.vm);  // Runs once the data is requested (no guarantee the promise has resolved yet).
```

As a result, any work that needs access to the data returned from the call **must** be put inside the `then` function, otherwise you have no guarantee that the data is available.

The output above is:

```
2 undefined
1 [your data object]
```

For more information on promises and asynchronous calls in Angular, this is a fantastic resource, and comes with cartoons! http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html